# Password Protected Document

Tags: c#, docusignapi

When creating a DocuSign package with password protected documents, I realize that when downloading the documents after the signing ceremony, the password protection was removed. 
Is that normal ?how does DocuSign do that ? is there a way to provide the password in the API so that the password protections remains the same ?

[image: Before DocuSign signing]

[image: After DocuSign signing]

Answer (score 4):

There are two types of password protection on a PDF document. The first requires a password just to open or access the document.  DocuSign doesn't try to circumvent such access protection.  To do so would be unethical.  If such an access-protected document is uploaded, DocuSign will reject it.  It is in this sense that "DocuSign does not support password protected documents."

(The documentation could be clearer and say something like, "DocuSign does not support access-protected documents, i.e. those that require a password to open them.")

The other kind of password controls the ability to change document permissions, e.g. to make a copy of the document, to print the document, or to edit text fields in the document.  DocuSign ignores these permissions, on the premise that a copy of the original document has been submitted to DocuSign with the express intention of allowing DocuSign to display it to signers, to digitally sign it and to make other modifications (all ultimately controlled by the user).  These permissions are not conveyed to the resulting DocuSign document because they no longer apply.

To respond to the original posted questions:

1. Depends on which type of password protection you are asking about.  Yes, it's normal and expected behavior for DocuSign to remove document permissions.  But DocuSign never opens a document which is access-protected by a password.
2. We do it by simply resetting the permission flags.  We already have complete control over the document since it was not password protected against access.  (With this level of control, the document permissions password is not needed to change the permission flags.)
3. If for some reason you want to set password protection or permissions on the resulting signed document, you could do so using any PDF manipulation tool that gives you that capability.  The DocuSign API doesn't support setting permissions or the permission password on the resulting document; it generally wouldn't make sense to do so.  For example, there are no longer any editable text fields, and the document has been signed; so edit protection would be moot.

Comment: Totally agree. Edit protection would be moot on a Signed document

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

`is there a way to provide the password in the API so that the password protections remains the same ?`

DocuSign does not support this.

From the official [Documentation](https://support.docusign.com/articles/Issues-Uploading-Documents-Common-Errors-Causes-and-Solutions)

> DocuSign does not support password protected documents.

See this [answer](https://support.docusign.com/en/answers/00003238) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for this link. So how does DocuSign can process the following ? "e can process ones that require a password to edit."

Comment: I would think that there would be official documentation originating from DocuSign explaining what they do and how when it comes to PDF permissions as DocuSign seems to bypass and remove some of those permissions

Comment: From the official [documentation](https://support.docusign.com/articles/Issues-Uploading-Documents-Common-Errors-Causes-and-Solutions)  `DocuSign does not support password protected documents.` The fact that you are able to upload password protected documents is probably a bug with DocuSign. I suggest you not upload password protected documents as DocuSign might reject such documents in future,

Comment: Im not sure if it's a bug but it's been working for several months. It might be because, like in the link you sent, I upload PDFs protected against editing that are taken by DocuSign fine. "Although we can process ones that are protected against editing by a password."